# App Engine Python Authentication Tutorial Broken?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get the App Engine [Authenticating Users with Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users) tutorial to work. I've followed the directions very carefully, using Google's own tutorial files. After logging in, evidently the session variables are not being created; according to the following code in base.html, I should be seeing my name (since I don't have a profile image stored):

```
{% if session.profile %}
  <a href="/logout">
    {% if session.profile.image %}
      <img class="img-circle" src="{{session.profile.image.url}}" width="24">
    {% endif %}
    {{session.profile.displayName}}
  </a>
{% else %}
  <a href="/oauth2authorize">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

When I click the "My Books" link (href="/books/mine"), I get an error: KeyError 'profile'. The handler for /mine is:

```
    @crud.route("/mine")
    @oauth2.required
    def list_mine():
        token = request.args.get('page_token', None)
        if token:
            token = token.encode('utf-8')

        books, next_page_token = get_model().list_by_user(
            user_id=session['profile']['id'],
            cursor=token)

        return render_template(
            "list.html",
            books=books,
            next_page_token=next_page_token)
```

The credentials are requested and passed to the Flask session variable in the `__init__.py` file:

```
def _request_user_info(credentials):
    """
    Makes an HTTP request to the Google+ API to retrieve the user's basic
    profile information, including full name and photo, and stores it in the
    Flask session.
    """
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)
    resp, content = http.request(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me')

    if resp.status != 200:
        current_app.logger.error(
            "Error while obtaining user profile: \n%s: %s", resp, content)
        return None
    session['profile'] = json.loads(content.decode('utf-8'))
```

The traceback points to line 66 of crud.py, which is `user_id=session['profile']['id'],` in the code above.

Here's the last series of traceback entries:

```
  File "/User/Joe/Documents/GitHub/appenginedeepdive-master/4-auth/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/contrib/flask_util.py", line 524, in required_wrapper
    return wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/User/Joe/Documents/GitHub/appenginedeepdive-master/4-auth/bookshelf/crud.py", line 66, in list_mine
    user_id=session['profile']['id'],
  File "/User/Joe/Documents/GitHub/appenginedeepdive-master/4-auth/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 377, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
KeyError: 'profile'
```

I tried running 'gcloud auth login' prior to executing the app, even though the instructions don't ask that you do, but I can't think of anything else to try. I've tried on both the local server (python main.py) and deploying to App Engine, but get the same error.

Checking Chrome's Developer Tools, there aren't any session variable created, but I can't figure out why not. Perhaps there's something related to the Flask framework I'm not getting.

Anyone got any ideas what's going on?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: The code assumes that `session['profile']['id']` is already filled in when the user authetication is performed. So either the authentication portion didn't happen or it didn't fill in the session as expected. But you're not showing that portion. Yes, this code could be written to handle this case a bit more graceful.

Comment: Try displaying `session['profile']` right after being set inside `_request_user_info()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, @DanCornilescu. I added the code from __init__.py where the credentials are requested and the session supposed to be set up. When I try to display 'profile' it throws an error - it's not finding it.

Comment: Well, you're just setting it, it *should* be there (I was just wondering if there was a content change since the guide was written). Unless the `session` itself is not working properly...

Comment: I tried displaying it in one of the HTML templates and that's what threw the error. It's looking like session itself isn't working - which might be some Flask issue.

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this, but that tutorial you are following is the first part of a longer tutorial that starts [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app). And now, more related to this case, are you generating the Flask secret as shown in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users#about_sessions), including adding the generated secret to the config.py?